# elastic: Error 500 (Internal Server Error): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception] when searching frequently through golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch, golang-migrate

I'm using golang to write a tool which can search the relating information about a list of userIds respectively. The program stopped with "elastic: Error 500 (Internal Server Error): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception] " for every 500 times of searching. I can continue the next 500 times searchs in about 5 minutes later. I wonder why this happens.

Comment: Whenever you encounter this error, I would suggest to check the shards health with `<es_host>/_cat/shards` api. If all okay there, trying running query from kibana to get actual detailed error. Also, check the `elasticsearch.log` file which can highlight actual underlying cause.